# MySQL connection refused for .net connector but not Workbench

Tags: mysql, .net, powershell, workbench

This is a very strange one.  I have a Windows system that I am trying to use to connect to a MySQL instance. That's not the strange part.

I have the proper grant permissions on the database for "user@10.10.10.10" (not the real IP address) and have tested the connection using MySQL Workbench 6.0.8. I can run a query like "SELECT * from users". That's not the strange part, either

The strange part began when I started to automate the task of pulling the data onto the client. I installed the .Net Connector version 6.9.4 and I am testing it in Powershell. From the **same** client using the **same** connection setting (hostname, user, and schema/database), I get an access denied error.

The problem is that the server is allowing Workbench as "user@10.10.10.10", but rejecting the .Net connector as "user@f.q.d.n". It seems that when connecting using the Workbench the server uses the IP address to match in the grant tables, but using the .Net Connector the server uses the reverse lookup FQDN instead.

I could ask the server admin to add "user@f.q.d.n" but I am curious as to why two different official Oracle/MySQL clients connecting from the same host would cause such different behavior.

Comment: Before anyone asks: yes, I have triple and quadruple checked the hostname, user name, etc in the connection string.

Comment: Also, in the working Workbench session, running the following query give these results: "SELECT user(), current_user();" returns "user@f.q.d.n, user@10.10.10.10".